# Woocommerce Order Completed Email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to find a way to send out an email once the order has been completed within WooCommerce store. How would I go about sending an auto email once the product/order has been ticked finish.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`WooCommerce` automatically send the processing email to user when you place any order and also send the mail to admin for new order you have to do nothing. Are you getting any type of error or something? because after installation all thing works automatically.

Comment: Yes right! woocommerce automatically send email on order completion.

Comment: So what was the problem? or you didn't test it before asking question?

Comment: I am not the question owner. :P